# Matlab supportpackageinstaller not presemt

Tags: matlab

I have just installed a fresh copy of elementary OS freya in my lappy and after that did an installation of matlab R2012b. First I tried using the image acquisition commands but they didn't work as the library was not there. To install I typed

```
supportpackageinstaller
```

but it gave an error

`Undefined function or variable 'supportPackageInstaller'.`

This is the first time I am installing matlab on linux so I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please run `imaqhwinfo` and post the output here? (E.g. edit your question and include that at the end)

Answer (score 0):

copied from: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/88896-how-to-install-add-on

the supportPackageInstaller is a **new feature in R2013b** and doesn't exist in older releases than R2013b. Which version are you using? If its not 13b you need to look up the support package on the File Exchange. Only for example Simulink Support Package for Arduino Mega 2560 Hardware (R2012a)

---

refer to another:
http://148.204.81.206/simulink/ug/start-support-package-installer.html#

Start Support Package Installer

You can use Support Package Installer to install support for specific third-party hardware and software products.

Support Package Installer guides you through the process of downloading and installing a support package.

To start Support Package Installer, use one of the following methods:

In a MATLAB® Command Window, enter targetinstaller.

In a model, select Tools > Run on Target Hardware > Install/Update Support Package.

Double-click a *.mlpkginstall file.

On the MATLAB tool strip, click Add-Ons and select Get Hardware Support Packages.